# I am looking for ElasticSearch equivalent of below query -

Tags: elasticsearch

```
SELECT sender
FROM julymonth
WHERE recipient IN ('x', 'y')
GROUP BY sender;
```

Here sender  and recipient are column names and julymonth is table name.

Answer (score 0):

Imaging your structure, this would be it:

```
POST /julymonth/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "recipient": [
            "x",
            "y"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "senders": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "sender",
        "size": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

1. Query part will filter your documents by recipient
2. Aggs will create a unique list of senders from your filtered documents

Comment: Thank You Evaldas, I was able to get the data, for the same query  please could you let me know how to get  the count of the senders.

Comment: This query brings these back too. Try looking for `doc_count` in your returned aggregations. You should see it.